# can't run git command in safe mode in android studio

Tags: android-studio

There is an error in my android studio when I go to setting -> version control -> git.
in that when I try to test my path then it shows that "can't run git command in safe mode".

I'm new to git and GitHub right now so still don't understand what the problem is.

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 3):

when you opened/imported the project you probably saw something like:
[image: this]

and you probably selected "stay in safe mode"

a fix:

head to:
file -> settings/preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Trusted Locations and add the path to your project or the directory that holds all of your projects (eg. C:\...\AndroidStudioProjects)

Answer (score 0):

I add my contribution because I was also stuck in safe mode, with some functionalities which had dissapeared (Git commit window). Adding the path of the project in the Trusted Locations didn't solve anything.

What worked in my case was to "Repair IDE": `File --> Repair IDE`.

After I performed this step, I saw a warning saying that the project was not trusted, and I could then "Trust Project", and everything came back to normal.